# Carousel slider break when I'm using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From my main page I include carousel file,

```
<div data-ng-include="'views/header/template/home_slider.html'"></div>
```

and home_slider.html contains following code,

```
<section class="carousel-wrapper" interval="myInterval.value" ng-if="isHome" ng-controller="slideCtrl">
        <div id="carousel-big">
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide1.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">

                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide2.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide1.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide2.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide1.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/img/slide2.jpg);">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>This is where title<br> goes, short or long</h1>
                    <p>by UserX</p>
                    <span>1000 views | 3 weeks ago</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">watch now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

after adding separate page using ng-include my carousel not working and the page totally break down but If I including those code into my main page then it's working fine. How can I solve It?

Comment: There should be an error in the console, what it states?

Comment: I already checked in console no error find out console.

Comment: 'interval="myInterval.value"' by adding interval also it doesnot work?

Comment: yes, It's not working.

Comment: `<div ng-include src="'views/header/template/home_slider.html'"></div>`
Try replacing with the above code

Comment: @GandharvGarg, please consider posting an answer if you have found the solution, in order to close the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write src after ng-include:

**REPLACE:**

```
<div data-ng-include="'views/header/template/home_slider.html'"></div>
```

**WITH**

```
<div ng-include src="'views/header/template/home_slider.html'"></div>
```

This will solve the issue.
[SOURCE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: There is no difference, useless